# Asp.Net Mvc - Replace Ajax.ActionLink with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to replace the following code with some JQuery code that use unobtrusive javascript instead of what the MicrosoftAjax library does ?

```
<ul class="vote">
   <li>
      <%= Ajax.ActionLink("Up", "UpVote", new { VoteId = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "upVote(this)" }, null) %>  
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a link with an Id attribute, then bind the click event to the function that will send the Ajax request.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Up","UpVote",new { VoteId = item.Id },new { id = "sendRequest" }) %>
```

Then with jQuery:

```
$('#sendRequest').click(function() {
  // $.getJSON or whatever ajax function you want to use
});
```